# ImageMagick, most efficient way to resize images?

Tags: php, api, laravel, image-resizing

```
$img = new imagick($image);
$img->setImageFormat($format);
if($format == 'jpg'){
   $img->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
   $img->setImageCompressionQuality(0);
         //$img->enhanceImage();
}
$img->adaptiveResizeImage(1500, 0);
$img->writeImage($PNG_IMAGE);
```

This still makes for a really grainy image compared to the original `.jpg-file`

How do I resize the image properly with as little grain/distortion/blur as possible?

Comment: I really like the [intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) image abstraction, which works with both imageMagick and GD, and plays very well with Laravel. A lot easier and cleaner code!

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll be sure to try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$img->setImageCompressionQuality(0)` sets the quality of the image. If you don't want to loose any quality set it to 100, but best for optimisation between 60-80.